# How can I update QTextEdit as user writes on it? (on Python)

Tags: python, qt

I'm working on a Python+Qt WebSMS app/script. It asks for a number and message, and sends it to Vodafone via mechanize. Since Vodafone of my country doesn't support UTF-8, at least for WebSMS and every SMS should be shorter than 160 chars, I'm using this setup:

```
def setMesaj():
  global mesaj
  mesaj = unicode(self.textEdit.toPlainText().toUtf8(), "utf-8")
  mesaj = mesaj.encode("ascii", "ignore")
  if (len(mesaj)) > 159:
    print "[WARN-1] Mesaj 160 karakterden fazla?"
    i = len(mesaj) - 159
    mesaj = mesaj [:-i]
  print mesaj


QtCore.QObject.connect(self.textEdit, QtCore.SIGNAL("textChanged()"), setMesaj)
```

Well, It works. If message goes over 160 chars, the last letter is automatically removed, and If user tries to type any "weird" character, It's not accepted.

Here's my question: The variable 'mesaj' works perfectly, but It doesn't update the QTextEdit thing, so when It doesn't get anything over 160 chars (or Unicode), it still looks like allowed to the user. So, how can I update QTextEdit as user writes on it and make the changes appear syncronized?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def setMesaj(self):
  mesaj = unicode(self.toPlainText().toUtf8(), "utf-8")
  ascii = mesaj.encode("ascii", "ignore")
  if ascii != mesaj:
    self.setPlainText(ascii)

  if (len(mesaj)) > 159:
    QtGui.QMessageBox.warning(self, 'warning', "[WARN-1] Mesaj 160 karakterden fazla?")
    i = len(mesaj) - 159
    mesaj = mesaj [:-i]
    self.setPlainText(mesaj)
```

This would be my quick and dirty approach, however you still have to put the text cursor in the correct position after making the edits.

Comment: Tried it and it worked flawlessly, thanks, but as you already said, text cursor was misplaced. Since it's going to work on a mobile device, It's an important problem for me now. Thank you anyway :) Let's see if there will be any better approach to do it. (not necessarily based on my code, just make it limit chars to 160 and remove unicode)

Comment: Yay ^^ Figured it out myself: cur = self.textEdit.textCursor() and cur.movePosition(QtGui.QtextCursor.End) then self.textEdit.setTextCursor(cur) did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One way to detect the right position for the text cursor would be to use [`codecs.register_error`](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#codecs.register_error) to define a custom error function, one that duplicates `"ignore"`, but also remembers how many characters in front of the cursor were deleted, and to shift the cursor that many positions to the left after encoding.

Comment: Thank you, can you give me a sample code about shifting the cursor to the left? or, can't I just move it to end? Also, this function is running after every letter, so I think there wouldn't be any need to remember how many characters were deleted, since only 1 character is deleted per run, isn't it correct?

Comment: Oh, in that case, you can just compare the length before and after, and move the cursor one to the left if the new length is less.